# Building HTML using code

Tags: java, html, string, stringbuilder

I have a staff record here and I need to let if go through a function and the function spits out the staff record nicely formatted with HTML tags.

example

```
staff id = 23422
first name = Herbert
surname = Dominos
department = Purchasing
```

function output would be something like

```
<label>staff id</label><div class="some class">23422</div>
<label>First namelabel><div class="some class">Herbert</div>
<label>Surname</label><div class="some class">Dominos</div>
<label>Department</label><div class="some class">Purchasing</div>
```

Seems just concatenating them via string or stringbuilder is not the right way to do it.

Any suggestions? thanks :)

Comment: What is the problem with concatenating strings. I don't see any real problem in it. If the problem is the quotes in 'class="some class"' you can simply escape them by typing \".

Comment: *"concatenating them via string or stringbuilder"*  If you mean `String` & `StringBuilder` then definitely no to the first.  As to whether it is best to use `StringBuilder` over many of the other ways of generating HTML, e.g. JSP or servlets, [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/).. - that is another matter.  I 'hand role' methods to do simple HTML structures like the cells and rows of tables.

Comment: If a lot of output remains the same and there are few places which will be filled in by Java ... a good alternative and more sophisticated way is to use "FreeMarker" ... for just a usecase you describe ... it may be an overkill

Comment: A good case against hand coding the strings can be seen in `<label>First namelabel>`  it should be `<label>First name</label>` ;)

Comment: @erik I got no problems with concatenating them. just wondering what others have used if they were in the same situation.

Comment: @AndrewThompson incorrect, after java 6 it doesn't matter which you use.

Comment: @AndrewThompson any other suggestion other than jsoup? looking at it now though. thanks :)

Comment: @jsshah looking into it. thanks :)

Comment: @Woot4Moo  Huh.  Thanks for the heads-up.  The 1.7 docs confirmed your statement, though they did not mention 'since when'.  :)

Comment: [JTidy](http://jtidy.sourceforge.net/) is another popular API, but search on 'html parser api java' & you should discover many.  If they can read HTML, they can generally write it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the [Java Anti-Template Language (JATL)](http://code.google.com/p/jatl/) would work for you.  It's coded using fluent API syntax.

Answer (score 0):

i would use apache [velocity](http://velocity.apache.org/) to achieve this.

example:

```
#foreach($staffInfo in $staffList.iterator())
<label>$staffInfo.getStaffId()</label>
#end
```

you can try something similar to construct your html code.

Comment: Yeah, it appears that Texen might do it.  Which of the velocity sub-projects are you referring to?

Comment: Yes Texen will help you out here. I usually use the engine itself. But Texen will be all that is required in your case.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this

```
<label>staff id </label><div class="some class">#staff id#</div>
<label>First namelabel><div class="some class">#First namelabel#</div>
<label>Surname</label><div class="some class">#Surname#</div>
<label>Department</label><div class="some class">#Department#</div>
```

and then I would use the replace function to replace for excample #Staff id# with 23422.

Quick, dirty, easy.